# Getting 404 pages when upgrading from 3.5.2 to 4.1.1

Tags: 404-error, upgrade

So strange but after doing a manual upgrade, most of the pages work except for these:

http://www.swa1.design2dev.com/report_card/commitments/country-commitments/burundi/

this works though: http://www.swa1.design2dev.com/commitments/all-commitments/

any tips on how to troubleshoot this?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried flushing your rewrite rules ? Go to: Settings -> Permalinks and just hit the save button :)

Comment: Did you modify WordPress Core?

Comment: no mods were made to the core.
@cristian.raiber - yes we tried that and flush_rewrite_rules(); still broken.